# Add my application in the share picker list

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

If suppose a user is watching an Youtube video and clicks on share button: 
I want my application to be available in that share picker listener. What should i do for that.

I searched over the internet but did not find any article related to this.

Please help me with any sources.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add intent filter in your manifest. For eg:- if you are viewing a picture and want to share it you need to add this to your activity in manifest

```
<intent-filter>
    <action
android:name="android.intent.
action.SEND" />
    <category
android:name="android.intent.
category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

To retrieve image add this in your activity

```
Uri imageUri = (Uri)
getIntent().getExtras().get
(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
```

Comment: Any example or tutorial will help alot..!

Comment: I couldn't find any tutorial that could explain you however I have edited the answer.